# Amazon AWS EC2 instance keeps disconnecting while using VS Code

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been running some code on an AWS EC2 instance. To access it, I usually connect using VS Code's Remote-SSH extension. The SSH-configuration file looks something like this:

```
Host aws-ec2
    HostName ec2-...compute-1.amazonaws.com
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile [path to file]
```

However, occasionally when I am working on some files, it suddenly disconnects and says it is having trouble reconnecting. At that point, I have to complete stop the instance, wait some time until it stops, start the instance again, wait until it starts, change the configuration file with new details, and then open it again.

I have tried simply rebooting the instance, but that does not work. This has happened many times over the past ~6 months. The Output tab shows something like this:

```
...
[00:39:12.906] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\ssh.exe ENOENT
[00:39:12.906] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[00:39:12.907] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[00:39:12.907] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[00:39:12.907] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[00:39:12.907] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[00:39:12.928] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3

[00:39:12.931] Running script with connection command: "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 56231 "aws-ec2" bash
[00:39:12.932] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[00:40:14.936] Resolver error: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
    at g.Timeout (c:\Users\S***\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:499860)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (c:\Users\S***\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:619259)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
[00:40:14.940] ------
```

**I have noticed any specific triggers to this happening; usually I am just coding in some file. Is there any way I can avoid this, or if not, is there an easier way that I can reload & continue working?**

**EDIT:** If I reboot and wait ~10 minutes it also works. But it will usually disconnect again soon.